# Use swank-js without js2-mode as major mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, slime, swank, js2-mode

I don't want to use `js2-mode` as major mode when editing js files. But I find I use `swank-js` very often(with [**magnar's slime-js setting**](https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-slime-js.el)).

Of course I know that swank-js depends on `js2-mode` Can I just `(require 'js2-mode)`(means not as major mode) and add some extra settings to enable `swank-js` ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use js2-mode? Maybe the problem is more easily fixed in that end.

Comment: @Magnar It seems that I just don't use many of its features. Sometimes `paredit-kill` not work very well in js2 but in js-mode. And can I stop its syntax check? Syntax check is good, but I just feel that js2-mode's syntax check is a bit ... I'm sorry for my broken English, I don't know how to describe it. I just feel uncomfortable when I am typing in js2 with its syntax check.

Comment: Yes, I know exactly how you feel. It is constantly telling me I have errors, when I'm just not done typing yet. You can turn it off with `(setq js2-mode-show-parse-errors nil)` - I don't know a fix for paredit-kill tho.

Comment: @Magnar Thanks for your comment, I'll try it soon later.

Comment: @Magnar After `(setq js2-mode-show-parse-errors nil)`, it seems nothing change. The minibuffer keep displaying error messages when typing.

Comment: @Magnar Another odd thing is even I've set `js2-idle-timer-delay` to 0.1 or 0.05, when I am typing I can feel that the highlight is delayed and maybe it's waiting for finishing parsing the file. That will not happen in any other major mode I've try as after I type a keyword they highlight it immediately. I don't know if js2 needs time to parsing a file, even within 10 lines.

Comment: @Magnar I've guess the simple highlight is separated from syntax check when I worked with a IDE before.

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course without the feature that requires `js2-mode` like smart evaluation of statement and function definition. I have to write a functions to have evaluation of line and region.